# Consulta openrowset no muestra decimales

Tags: sql-server

Al consultar un archivo .csv no muestra las decimales que están en el archivo.

```
select *
from 
openrowset ('msdasql','driver={microsoft text driver (*.txt; *.csv)}; 
defaultdir=f:\Temp\Presupuesto\Formatos Ingreso\;' 
 ,'select * from ConsumoEPIC.csv')
```

En algún apartado de la sintaxis puedo definir los tipos de datos de las columnas ?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es un ejemplo de como esta mi archivo .csv el cual muestra las decimales en la columna de Mar, pero al hacer la consulta me quita los decimales.

Comment: Puedes usar un archivo de formato. Con más información de lo que contiene, podría dar un ejemplo.

Comment: Agregue un ejemplo de mi archivo .csv

Comment: Eso es una imagen de Excel, el archivo csv debe de ser en texto.